# Modernizr 3.x not working on firefox 18-21

Tags: firefox, modernizr

Modernizr 3.x not working on firefox 18-21 (both windows and mac). I've tried getting rid of all the tests that were raising a warning/error but am now left with just an unexplained "Error:". Any thoughts?

Comment: Firefox 18 is three years old, and should be autoupdated. Why would you be using it? What is the actual Error you are receiving? can you post a demo?

Comment: The issue is with all 4 browsers from 18 through 21. and I have a requirement for my script to work on all browsers available on crossbrowsertesting/browserstack. The error I get on windows is simply "Error" with no description while on mac I get:                                  [08:25:19.135] Error: Permission denied to access object
[08:25:19.135] Error: 
[08:25:19.141] ReferenceError: Modernizr is not defined

Answer (score 0):

FIXED, either "RTC Data Channel" or "RTC Peer Connection" tests crash in these versions of firefox, once I removed them it fixed the problem.